Trying to make a map display as a clickable button
I'm only 2 weeks in to coding in Flutter and I'm creating an app that simply shows a list of restaurants along with their location. I've made the widgets as stateful and have fed data into my app through a local json file that I have stored in an assets directory I created in the root of the folder.
I've managed to finish almost everything. For the maps section, I've displayed the location with marker using Open street maps, but I want to make that display as a clickable button that opens google maps via the url launcher. I've done the code and everything, but unfortunately it does not open. Following is the block of code in question:
SizedBox(
  width: 500,
  height: 300,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () async {
      final String googleMapsUrl =
          "comgooglemaps://?center=${restaurantDataModel.latitude},${restaurantDataModel.longitude}";
      if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(googleMapsUrl))) {
        await launchUrl(Uri.parse(googleMapsUrl));
      } else {
        throw "Could not launch Url";
      }
    },
    child: FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        initialCenter: LatLng(
          restaurantDataModel.latitude,
          restaurantDataModel.longitude,
        ),
        initialZoom: 15,
        interactionOptions: InteractionOptions(
          flags: ~InteractiveFlag.doubleTapZoom,
        ),
      ),
      children: [
        openStreetMapTileLayer,
        MarkerLayer(
          markers: [
            Marker(
              point: LatLng(
                restaurantDataModel.latitude,
                restaurantDataModel.longitude,
              ),
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.location_pin,
                size: 40,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

Appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Try to print something within onPressed() of InkWell. If it's working then try to change your maps url:
FROM:
final String googleMapsUrl =
          "comgooglemaps://?center=${restaurantDataModel.latitude},${restaurantDataModel.longitude}";

TO:
  final String googleMapsUrl =
          "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${restaurantDataModel.latitude},${restaurantDataModel.longitude}";


Thanks for the comment. I tried this, and my code runs. But the url doesn't launch. I tried to look this up and it says its an emulator issue. Do you know a work around to that?

Just try with a real device once and add the error in your question
